# Exact search for labels in LyX

Tags: lyx, search

Say I have labels "ABC", "ABC1", "ABC2", etc.

In the Outline pane > "Labels and References", how do I search for "ABC" without "ABC1", "ABC2", etc. also showing up?

Comment: I don't think this feature exists. In this case, I would open up the .lyx file and search in my text editor. For example, I would open in Vim and search for `\<ABC\>` for the exact search. Then I would look at the surrounding text so I know what to search for back in LyX. I know this isn't a good workaround, but I still note it just in case.

Comment: Labels itself have not level hierarchy, and can be used not only for sections, but also for figures and tables, so you can hide subsections the ToC pane,  but not their labels, for instance (afaik, of course).